# How to remove specific value from multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my array and i want to remove specific value from array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => categoryfilter
            [value] => 127
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => price_min
            [value] => sd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => price_max
            [value] => sdsd
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => action
            [value] => myfilter
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => quantity
            [value] => 1
        )
);
```

I want to remove all `quantity` key items from array .

I have tried using following way but not remove display same thing.

```
if (($key = array_search('quantity', $_POST['product'])) !== false) {
    unset($_POST['product'][$key]);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST['product']);
```

Comment: @SzántóZoltán He doesn't want to delete a whole column, he wants to delete the rows where a column matches a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array.

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $k => $p) {
    if ($p['name'] == 'quantity') {
        unset($_POST['product'][$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` with `callback` function

```
 $f = array_filter($a, function($v){return $v['name'] != 'quantity';});
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/DqoLj